# No additional driver listed

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I can't find any additional driver listed in my ubuntu 12.10. I've checked the following command and it shows like i've got NVIDIA card for sure. I've got NVIDIA GEFORCE GT520M.

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0ded (rev ff)
```

So can you please help me to get my NVIDIA driver to work out? I'm quite confused that everybody can see additional driver for their NVIDIA cards. Is it only me who can't see the additional drivers for NVIDIA Card? Please help me. And I can't post my screenshots as i've not enough reputations. :(

Comment: If you'd like to post images, I would recommend uploading them to imgur or somewhere similar and providing links in your question. Someone with enough rep will likely edit them in for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the output of **lspci | grep VGA**, You have the Optimus technology laptop

Bumblebee aims to provide support for NVIDIA Optimus laptops for GNU/Linux distributions. Using Bumblebee, you can use your NVIDIA card for rendering graphics which will be displayed using the Intel card.

So you need to install bumblebee to get **Nvidia Working** on Ubuntu, Just copy paste the following commands one by one in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic -y 
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

after that

```
 sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

edit the following Driver=

```
Driver=nvidia
```

Reboot and you can run the application from Nvidia

```
 optirun firefox    # As i am running Firefox in this example
```

[S O U R C E](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)